# Simple understanding of Orthogonal Distance Regression (ODR)

Tags: scipy, regression, curve-fitting, data-fitting, orthogonal

I have some data points with errors in both the x and y coordinates on these data points. I therefore want to use python's ODR tool to compute the best-fit slope and the error on this slope. I have tried doing it for my actual data but do not find good results. Therefore, I have first tried to use ODR with a simple example as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.odr import *

def linear_func(B, x):
    return B[0]*x+B[1]

x_data=np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
y_data=np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
x_err=np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
y_err=np.array([5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0])

linear=Model(linear_func)
data=RealData(x_data, y_data, sx=x_err, sy=y_err)
odr=ODR(data, linear, beta0=[1.0, 0.0])
out=odr.run()
out.pprint()
```

The `pprint()` line gives:

```
Beta: [ 1.  0.]
Beta Std Error: [ 0.  0.]
Beta Covariance: [[  5.20000039  -7.80000026]
 [ -7.80000026  18.1999991 ]]
Residual Variance: 0.0
Inverse Condition #: 0.0315397386692
Reason(s) for Halting:
  Sum of squares convergence
```

The resutling Beta values are shown to be 1.0 and 0.0, which I would epect. But why are the standard errors, `Beta Std Error`, also both zero if my errors on the data points are quite large? Can anyone offer some insight?

Answer (score 3):

I see no discrepancy here. Your example model fits your data perfectly, so the weights you pass to the data do not matter. Moreover, your initial guess `beta0=[1.0, 0.0]` is a parameter vector giving an optimal solution, so the ODR machinery can not find an iterative improvement of the parameters and quits after zero iterations. The associated errors are zero because for a given data the solution found is infinitely better than any other solution possible because your [sum of squares](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPerpendicularOffsets.html) at `B=[1, 0]` is zero.

To see the what actually happens inside `ODR.run()` function, add `odr.set_iprint(init=2, iter=2, final=2)` before you run the regression. In particular, the following output confirms that ODR reaches the stopping condition immediately:

```
 --- STOPPING CONDITIONS:
         INFO =     1 ==> SUM OF SQUARES CONVERGENCE.
        NITER =     0          (NUMBER OF ITERATIONS)
```

Note how the errors will *not* be zero, and `NITER` will be an integer number if either your `x_data` is unequal to `y_data` or if `beta0` does not match the optimal solution. In that case, the errors returned by ODR will be nonzero, although still incredibly small.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer, Vlas. What I don't understand is why there isn't some fundamental error on the slope. I thought ODR was supposed to compute the inherent error in the slope of the line as well as its value if given data with error bars. How does one compute the inherent error on the slope if not this way?

Comment: The value of `Beta Std Error` does not reflect the absolute error that you pass to it - only the relative "weights" assigned to the data points. I do not fully understand how those values are calculated, but perhaps you can figure it out by reading through ordpack [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/external/odrpack_guide.pdf).

Comment: One way to factor in your absolute scalings of `x_err` and `y_err` is to estimate your parameter uncertainties as `B_err = np.sqrt(np.diag(out.cov_beta))` - the square root of the diagonal entries of the covariance matrix. Section `4.B` in the linked doc above goes into a bit of detail on how good of an approximation this is.